# JQuery function returning an object but its being integrated as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get an object from function on button click.

The function is returning an object(checked using Google tool) but the return value "tr" becomes undefined.

Button

```
    $("#btnView").on("click", function () {
        var tr = GetActiveRow();       <-- the tr value is coming as undefined 
        var itemNumber = tr.find("td").eq(0).html();
    });
```

Function

```
function GetActiveRow() {
var rows = $(".datagrid tr:gt(0)");
rows.each(function (index) {
    //If its currently active override it so we can mark new row

    var rowdata = $(this).data;
    if ($(this).data("isActive") == true) {
        alert($(this));
        return $(this).get(); <-----object is being turned because the alert message is displayed 
    }
});
}
```

Comment: will one of the tr be active at a time?

Answer (score 0):

i was jumping out of the loop added return statement at the bottom and it worked :D

```
function GetActiveInvoiceRow() {
var trRow = null;
var rows = $(".datagrid tr:gt(0)");
rows.each(function (index) {
    //If its currently active override it so we can mark new row
    var rowdata = $(this).data;
    if ($(this).data("isActive") == true) {
        trRow = $(this);
        return;
    }
});

return trRow;
}
```